# Illustrating a multi-page MWE

Tags: support, images, mwe

I've often found that it is helpful to post a image with your MWE. In cases where you're using a single-Page MWE, ImageMagick's 'convert' utility does the trick. For multi-page MWEs (e.g. for questions on page-breaking), it's trickier. I would like to be able to produce something like this (from an answer by David Carlisle)[image]

How should one do this?

Comment: Good question! It should go on [meta], however. I've voted to migrate. It might be found to be a duplicate there, I don't remember if the existing questions cover multi-page stuff.

Comment: I'm very happy to migrate it -- does that involve closing and reasking? [I also have an answer which I'm in the middle of typing up!]

Comment: I normally adjust the page geometry (if needed) and use `Two Page View` from Acrobat to capture the image from the screen.

Comment: @Mohan Migration-question answered, I suppose `:)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest solution I've found involves using the `pdfpages` package:

1. Compile the MWE into a pdf.
2. `pdfpages` allows "Several logical pages [to] be arranged onto each sheet of paper", like so:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{nopageno}
   \usepackage{pdfpages}

   \begin{document}
   \includepdf[nup=4x4,pages={1-16},frame=true]{<filename>.pdf}
   \end{document}
   ```

   (Adjust the `nup` to get however many rows and columns you want.)
3. Compile the tex document from 2. to a pdf.
4. Use convert to extract a turn this new .pdf into a .png.

You will end up with something like this:[image]

Comment: Why isn't my code formatting properly?

Comment: You need 8 spaces inside a list for code formatting.

Comment: Also see [Why do code snippets not work after lists?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1558/5764).

Comment: Additional note: If you want to compare several MWEs side-by-side, the `\includepdfmerge` command from the `pdfpages` package will allow you to arrange several logical pages on the same sheet of paper, even if the logical pages come from different pdf files.

Answer (score 4):

I find the simplest is to upload the PDF directly via the image upload facility on the site and it puts all the pages in the PDF into the question/answer.  The only issue with that is that the default resolution of the conversion isn't all that high.

For example, here's a pdf with several pages uploaded via the imgur upload:

[image: multipage PDF upload]

Comment: That works well in your beamer example, but I've had problems in cases where it's not clear where the bottom of a page is (e.g. in pagebreaking questions). The `frame` option in `includepdf` helps with this by supplying a grid.

Comment: How can you do this now, as the site doesn't allow to use the tool now?